# lodash orderBy on collection add an orderIndex property

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I am using loadsh version `4.17.15` to ordering a collection on basis of `posted` time in milliseconds as below:

```
import {orderBy,findIndex,find} from 'lodash';

getSortedPosts=(list)=>{
     const ls = orderBy(list,['posted'],'desc');
     return ls;
}
```

I want to add a new property `orderIndex` (order sequence number) to the collection.
Is there a `lodash` way of doing this?

Comment: What's wrong with indexOf ?

Comment: To which collection? to `['posted']`?

Comment: @AlekseyL. to add property `orderIndex` to each object in `list` array

Comment: Do you mean within the `orderBy` call? No because it doesn't modify the contents. But you can do it with simple map or forEach afterwards

Comment: @AlekseyL. Ok. Which means got to loop the large list again :(

Comment: Not sure what scenario do you have, but you'll probably need to loop the list anyway to render or whatever, so you'll get the index at this point